# Conditional redirectTo in routes

Tags: angular, routes

I can define a static redirect in the routes array

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
];
```

We are using the `redirectTo` to tell angular route service if the users navigate to the empty URL they should be redirected to the home URL rather than the empty URL.

I need that rule to be dynamic. Depending on the condition, I need to redirect the user to the products page instead of the home page.

Comment: In which case should the user be redirected to the product page ?

Comment: you might need a loading component which does some logic and then redirects depending on state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a separate service which listens to router event RouteRecognised and redirects when it's necessary.

```
this.router.events
        .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized))
        .subscribe((e: RoutesRecognized) => {
            if (condition) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl((newUrl, { replaceUrl: true });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom guard which implements CanActivate. You should add it to route like this:

```
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
```

and then redirect to route you want to depending on dynamic conditions.

Example at [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#guard-the-admin-feature) (auth guard).

Comment: This guard is not working when we navigate from route nested in the route with the guard (it's already activated).